# Lotus Notes Field does not refresh automatically on document open

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

One of my fields in a form in notes designer has the following code:

```
viewhire := @If(@IsMember(@UserName; WillNotify);@UserName;
    @IsMember("[SuperUser]";@UserRoles);@UserName;
    @IsMember("[Finance]"; @UserRoles);@UserName;"INVALID");

@Name([Abbreviate];viewhire)
```

The problem with this code is the first person to open the document has his username set in this field. So the next time a different user trys to open the same document his name does not appear in the field till he refreshes the document only then his username gets inserted in the field.

Any ideas to over come this problem ? One way I thought of is if i can insert this code on "Open document" then it will solve it but i am not sure or know if this is possible ?

I am using Domino Designer 8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the field as "Computed for Display" rather than "Computed"  and the field will be calculated on document open properly. 
The only disadvantage is that the field is not stored in the document though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... i tried changing the field to Computed For Display but now it always shows the value as "Invalid" for that field when a document is opened ? I tried opening like 20 odd documents and they all said invalid not sure why ?

Comment: What is the value and type of the field WillNotify? I assume this is another field on the firm, isnt it? what roles does the user have? If the db is local: is consistent acl enabled? I suggest that you test the three conditions separately for debugging reasons to find out which conditions pass or fail.

Comment: the consistent acl was disabled on the local copy ..enabled it and now it is working fine. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Leave the field as computed and put the following in the form PostOpen :

Source.refresh

This causes an immediate recalculation of field formulas as the form opens regardless of edit mode or not, but wont work on the web.

Comment: Did you ever try to do a notesuidocument.refresh in read mode? It will simply not work and throw an error like "document command not available"...

Comment: Yes that command did not work "Source.refresh" in read mode. I got the error Document command not available.